# The polynomial of Lost's numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, integers

In the Lost tv series frequently appear numbers $4,8,15,16,23,42$ which can be represented by the following polynomial (when $x=1,2,3,4,5,6$):

$$P(x)=60-\frac{612}{5}x+\frac{367}{4}x^{2}-\frac{235}{8}x^{3}+\frac{17}{4}x^{4}-\frac{9}{40}x^{5}.$$

I found it interesting that although all polynomial coefficients (except $ 60 $) are rational numbers, it seems that if $ x $ is an integer then $ P (x) $ will be an integer.
How can it be proven?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step one: Transform it into

$$P(x) = \frac{Q(x)} a$$

where $Q(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients and $a$ is a positive integer.

Step 2:
Show (e.g. with a computer) for all integers $0 \leq b \leq a-1$ that $Q(b) \equiv 0 \bmod a$.

Step 3: Use the rules of modulo arithmetic to see that you are done.

edit: The Lost Numbers have their own [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A104101) page? Really?

Comment: Yes, is the A104101 page .... (LOL)

Comment: Literate English-speaking people call it "modular arithmetic". Some of those whose only encounter with it is in school call it "modulo arithmetic". $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks. Learning something new every day. :)